# Can't change footbibrule

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes

I've loaded the `footbib` package and the `\footcite` command is working.  The [user manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/footbib/footbib.pdf) says "The height of the skip and the horizontal line may be redefined in
the preamble by `\setlength\footbibskip{...}`
`\renewcommand\footbibrule{...}`"

In `footbib.sty` its definition is `\footbibrule{\kern-3\p@{\hrule}\kern 2.6\p@}` but changing it gives a LuaLaTeX error e.g.

> ```
>    \footbibrule undefined.                                          
>
> l.76 \renewcommand{\footbibrule}
>                              {\kern-4\p@{\hrule}\kern 2.6\p@}
> ```

I wanted to change its colour and length and found the workaround that `\renewcommand{\footnoterule}` does what I want, but I don't see why it's not possible to `\renewcommand{\footbibrule}`

MWE is

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, % Stock and paper size.
11pt, % Type size.
article
]{memoir}

\usepackage[autocite=footnote,%
backend=biber,%
block=space,%
style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[citeonce(page),citeonce(chapter)]{footbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footbibrule}{\kern-4\p@{\hrule}\kern 2.6\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{VERN1966,
       author = {Vernes, J.-R.},
       title = {Bridge Moderne de la Défense},
       publisher = {L'Éditions Bridgeur},
       pages={44--48},
       language = {Français},
       date = {1966}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document} 
The LOTT goes back to Vernes \footcite{VERN1966}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Since you are using `footbib` I have removed the `biblatex` tag.

Comment: The `footmisc` documentation does mention neither `footbibrule` nor `footbib`.

Comment: In the MWE you don't load `footbib` any more. It's not surprising it doesn't work like that. Your MWE is slightly too minimal, I'm afraid. You need to load at least `footbib` (and your other bibliography packages and settings).

Comment: Sorry - I pasted the wrong stuff making the MWE.  That's now fixed.  The initial error then becomes "Package footbib Error: the output routine of LaTeX changed."  which isn't produced in my actual system.  It then goes on to "Undefined control sequence.
\footbibrule ->\kern -4\p [There's a line break here]
                                                                                          @{\hrule }\kern 2.6\p @" which suggests the "@" is implicated.  But I did previously try a renewcommand that had no "@"!

Comment: Ah! Yes, you need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around code that uses `@`: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\footbibrule}{\kern-4\p@{\hrule}\kern 2.6\p@}\makeatother`. We can't really test your MWE further since we don't have your `.bib` files and I suspect the MWE is still missing your bibliography setup.

Comment: When I add those into the MWE it gives "Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'footbib'." which I suppose is the root problem.  It all works fine in my live though - I wonder if something else is supplying footcite (there's no mention in the log of the package being loaded).

Comment: Oh, so you are using `biblatex` after all. `footbib` is incompatible with `biblatex` as stated. `biblatex` has its own `\footcite`. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: That explains why my original workaround works!  So there's really no issue - I can do what I want without footbib.  I was mostly curious why the renewcommand didn't work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`\footbibrule` is defined by `footbib`. But `footbib` is incompatible with `biblatex`. You can't use both at the same time. `biblatex` already defines `\footcite`. And with a bit of work you should be able to do most things `footbib` can with `biblatex` as well.